# SSH over dedicated OpenVPN connection

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I have several SSH servers I want to connect to that can only be reached via (different) OpenVPN networks.

Now my question is: I have for each network a different set of certificates and sightly varying configurations (*.crt, *.key, *.ovpn). Since my servers can be moved from one network to another (often twice or more per day) I was wondering if there is a simple wrapper for ssh/vpn that allows me to call:

```
 ssh server1@network.com -ovpn "ovpnfile" -cert "cert.crt"
```

So that I only have to change the servername each time. That wrapper should automatically tunnel my ssh connection through openvpn and terminate the connection when I close the ssh connection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Prerequesits:

- Replace every "redirect-gateway" or "route" in your openvpn files
  with "##SERVERROUTE##"
- Make sure that you can resolve Hostnames to
  IP-Adresses

---

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPFILE=/tmp/._chrissvpn_$RANDOM

SSHSERVER=`echo $1| cut -d "@" -f 2`

SSHSERVIP=`host $SSHSERVER | head -n 1 | awk '{print $4}'`

cat $2 | sed 's/##SERVERROUTE/$SSHSERVIP/g' > $TMPFILE

openvpn --config $TMPFILE

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then

    ssh $1

fi
```